# When we have complaints against moderation is raising a meta the only or recommended solution?

Tags: discussion, support, moderators

Usually when i find unfair instances of moderation, i straightaway post on here.

Is this practice ok or something else is also recommended (like discussing in chat rooms etc) in such situations?

Personally, i always prefer posting a Meta question, so that everyone can see what my complaint is and share their views on it. If i chat instead with moderators, then not many people of our community are getting aware of the complaint or the discussion done to sort it out. And, i want all of them to be involved.

The reason, i am asking for an official stand on the issue here, is because, sometimes in the past, when i raised such complaints, some users commented thus " This is not the correct way of posting on Meta" etc.

Another question- Can users like me directly complain to Community Mods about unfair moderation? Will such complaints be considered?

Comment: "An 'actor' is a good 'actor', when their 'acting' doesn't feel like 'acting'." Now, replace "act" with "moderate" and re-read. In many SE sites, the moderation is so subtle, that a day to day users don't even notice it. If any unfair moderation is very noticeable, then Meta is a proper place IMO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[What recourse do I have if I believe a moderator has abused his/her privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28867/163449)

> If you have a dispute with a diamond moderator your options are:
>
> - Send a message to the Stack Exchange team via the "contact us" link at the bottom of any page with your complaint and links to the
>     questions/answers.
> - Flag for moderator attention and request a second moderator to have a look.
>
> For the record, here are levels of moderation (from highest to
>   lowest):
>
> - Stack Exchange Employees ([community team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-team-and-what-do-they-do),
>     devs)
> - [Diamond Moderators](http://stackexchange.com/about/moderators) - Elected by community or appointed as Moderators "pro tempore" for beta-sites.
> - Regular users with [rep-based privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges?tab=moderation)
>
> Some unsolicited advice:
>
> *It's often best for you to try to work things out at as low a level as possible.* If you have a problem with one moderator, it's faster
>   for you to reach any of the other elected "Diamond Moderators" on your
>   site as they have the most experience with your specific site and may
>   even have seen other actions you have taken that give context to the
>   issue at hand. Sometimes you want to go above someone's head (or even
>   straight to the top) with a complaint or request, but realize that the
>   recipient will wonder why this person with a complaint couldn't
>   resolve it with the team of moderators that were put in place to do
>   just that.

---

Good moderation is ought to be subtle, and usually it's discipline driven (i.e. maintains the decorum of the site). In some of the other SE sites, moderation is usually hardly noticeable.
If any unfair moderation is explicit, then local Meta is a proper place.

Comment: 1. According to the answer raising a Meta is not even listed as a solution. What if problem is not sorted out even after getting attentions of other Mods? 2. Anyways u have answered my "another question" in a Yes.

Comment: @Rickross, "raising the issue in meta" is a good way for the problem description in your Qn. But since that's my personal opinion, I have put it as a comment. It probably was not the "best" official way, when the above answer was written. That answer actually ignores the fact, that many times the help-centre Mods offer deaf ear to any such complains.

Comment: That answer actually ignores the fact-- Yes so, this is not quite the best suggestion for our site in particular. @iammilind

Comment: You should add to the answer few of ur own lines/opinions too. Because, right now, posting a question on meta is not even listed. I can not accept this answer, because the suggestions mentioned don't really work.

Comment: @Rickross, since that answer is not completely mine, I have made it a wiki. A wiki-answer also means that anyone (even less reputation) can edit it. Hence, you may add the appropriate parts, which makes it acceptable.

Comment: No i am asking for other users' opinions here. So, what i am saying is u can add ur opinions too in it. Because, in comments u said that raising a meta is the solution. So, if u can add that in the answer too? @iammilind